# from_personal_row() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below ([and linked in full here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gbrodman/order-tracking/e4729fd8c7a5297925d9440a994ddae1be4dd245/import_report.py)) is attempting to read from a .csv uploaded to Google Sheets, however I cannot get past the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_report.py", line 211, in <module>
    main()
  File "import_report.py", line 163, in main
    all_trackings.extend(objects_to_sheet.download_from_sheet(from_personal_row, sheet_id, tab_name))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 329, in wrapped_f
    return self.call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 409, in call
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 368, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 412, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\order-tracking\lib\objects_to_sheet.py", line 26, in download_from_sheet
    return [from_row_fn(header, value) for value in values]
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\order-tracking\lib\objects_to_sheet.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    return [from_row_fn(header, value) for value in values]
TypeError: from_personal_row() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I've read a lot of threads regarding similar errors other posters have encountered, but I can't figure out how to apply the advice here.

**Google Sheet CSV:**
[image: Google Sheet CSV]

**Code:**

```
def from_personal_row(row: Dict[str, str]) -> Optional[Tracking]:
tracking_col = row['Carrier Name & Tracking Number']
if not tracking_col:
   return None
tracking = tracking_col.split('(')[1].replace(')', '')
orders = {row['Order ID'].upper()}
price_str = str(row['Subtotal']).replace(',', '').replace('$', '').replace('N/A', '0.0')
price = float(price_str) if price_str else 0.0
to_email = row['Ordering Customer Email']
ship_date = get_ship_date(str(row["Shipment Date"]))
street_1 = row['Shipping Address Street 1']
city = row['Shipping Address City']
state = row['Shipping Address State']
address = f"{street_1} {city}, {state}"
group, reconcile = get_group(address)
if group is None:
  return None
tracked_cost = 0.0
items = price_str
merchant = 'Amazon'
return Tracking(
  tracking,
  group,
  orders,
  price,
  to_email,
  ship_date=ship_date,
  tracked_cost=tracked_cost,
  items=items,
  merchant=merchant,
  reconcile=reconcile)
```

Comment: It means you pass two parameters to the function ```from_personal_row```, can you show me the code where you call ```from_personal_row```?

Comment: You need to figure out what "row" is here "return [from_row_fn(row) for row in rows]"

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: function is defined with one argument `row: Dict[str, str]` but later is used in `read_trackings_from_file` which expects `Callable[[Dict[str, str]], Tracking]` with two arguments`[Dict[str, str]]` and `Tracking`

Comment: @ToanTran https://github.com/gbrodman/order-tracking/blob/e4729fd8c7a5297925d9440a994ddae1be4dd245/import_report.py

Comment: @furas, my apologies. I have pasted the full traceback now.

Comment: your error shows `from_row_fn(header, value)` so it runs function `from_row_fn` with two values but I checked other lines in code and in one place it does something similar to `from_row_fn = from_personal_row` - so now it uses `from_personal_row(header, value)` and this makes problem - `from_personal_row` can get only one value `from_personal_row(row: Dict[str, str])`. So maybe you should use `dict()` to run `from_row_fn( dict((header, value)) )`